# How do I show progress of file upload in react using File Reader on progress event

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to show the progress of my file upload in my react project using File reader API on progress event, But I am not sure How to do it
Below is my custom upload button.

```
export const CustomUploadButton = (props) => {

// Create a reference to the hidden file input element
const hiddenFileInput = useRef(null);

const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

const [completed,setCompleted] = useState([])


const addListeners = (reader,index) => {
    console.log(`event listner ${index}`);
    reader.addEventListener('loadstart', (e) => {handleEvent(e,index)});
    reader.addEventListener('load', (e) => {handleEvent(e,index)});
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', (e) => {handleEvent(e,index)});
    reader.addEventListener('progress', (e) => {handleEvent(e,index)});
}

const handleEvent = (event,index) =>{
    console.log(`ssssssssss === ${event}`);
    let temoCOmplete = []
    if (event.loaded && event.total) {
        const percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        console.log(`Progress: ${Math.round(percent)}`);
        temoCOmplete[index] = Math.round(percent)
        setCompleted(temoCOmplete)
      }      
}

const [fileListArray,setFileListArray] = useState([])
// let fileListArray = []
let fileDataArray= []
const handleChange = (event) => {
    let files = event.target.files
    if(files != null){
        let file = []
        const reader = new FileReader();
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                reader.onprogress = (ev) => {
                    if (ev.loaded && ev.total) {
                        const percent = (ev.loaded / ev.total) * 100;
                        console.log(`Progress: ${Math.round(percent)}`);
                    }
                }
                file.push(files[i])
        }
        setFileListArray(file)
        // console.log(`**** ${file} *****`)
    }
}

  // Programatically click the hidden file input element
  // when the Button component is clicked
  const handleClick = event => {
    hiddenFileInput.current.click();
  };

let downLoadFile = (index)=>{
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileListArray[index])
    window.open(objectURL,"_blank")
}
```

I just need to understand how the event is triggered for each fie and how to call the File Reader API in my code